# sql query on joomla

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

i wasnt able to retrive fields from Joomla from 2 tables , the problem is the query return always 3 result but should return 2 result

```
public function getAgent(){
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select(array('ag.company_id','ag.first_name','ag.last_name'));
        $query->from('#__cddir_agent AS ag');
        $query->join('INNER','#__cddir_company AS c ON ag.company_id = c.id');
        $data = $db->setQuery($query);
        $result = $db->loadObjectList();
         return $result;
    }
```

can anyone tell me where is my issue 
thanks

Comment: So you're trying to set a limit on how many results are returned?

Comment: no the problem is that the result should return 2 result but it returs always 3 and i didnt understand why !!!! O.o

Comment: did you try left join instead of inner??

Comment: i did try it but left join returned for me all the 4 result in the table

Comment: how about left inner?

Comment: i did it , also return 3 result from the table , i was trying to solve this now 3 hours ~X( and no slution

Comment: return also 3 result ...

Comment: what 2 result you want?  first name an last name?

Comment: yes , exactly i need to return the first name and the last name of the agent where the id = company id

Answer (score 0):

The query returns 3 because you are asking it to return 3 column fields in the line:

```
$query->select(array('ag.company_id','ag.first_name','ag.last_name'));
```

If you want to return 2 fields then ask it to return 2 column fields like

```
$query->select(array('ag.first_name','ag.last_name'));
```